# Error while processing multiple files in sub-routine argument

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute the below script and perl says that the read-only variable is getting modified. I couldn't find which variable is getting modified in this program. Can anyone please help me how to fix this error in the below script ?

```
 1. use strict;
 2. use warnings;
 3. use diagnostics;
 4. use vars;
 5. use 5.010;
 6. #--------------------------------------------#
 7.
 8. my @array;
 9. if (! open STDERR, ">", "error.txt") {
10.      die "cannot open the Error file for write";}
11. &config_parser ('O3CPU.py','config.ini');
12. #print "\nNo of elemnts is ". scalar @temp. "\n";
13.
14. sub config_parser {
15.             foreach (@_) {
16.                 
17.             if (! open HANDLE1, "<", "$_" ){
18.                 die "Cannot open $_: $!"; } 
19. 
20.             my @array;
21.             while (<HANDLE1>) {
22.             
23.                 chomp $_;   
24.                 if ($_=~ (s/Fetch\s?width/Fetch width /i)               || 
25.                             (s/Issue\s?width/Issue width /i)                ||
26.                         (s/Decode\s?width/Decode width /i)      ||
27.                         (s/Rename\s?width/Rename width /i)      ||
28.                         (s/wb\s?width/Writeback width /i)       || 
29.                         (s/Commit\s?width/Commit width /i)          ||
30.                         (s/LQEntries/Load queue size /i)            ||
31.                         (s/SQEntries/Store queue size /i)           ||
32.                         (s/ROBEntries/ROB buffer size /i)       ||
33.                         (s/Int\s?Regs/Integer registers /i)             ||
34.                         (s/Float\s?Regs/Floating point registers /i)    ||
35.                         (s/Pred\s?Type/Branch predictor type /i)    ||
36.                         (s/Global\s?pred\w+/Global predictor size/i) ||
37.                         (s/Local\s?pred\w+/Local predictor size/i)  ||
38.                         (s/Local\s?Hist\w+/Local History table size/i)
39.                        
40.                     ){
41.                          print "$_\n";
42.                          push @array, "$_";
43.                          }
44.
45.                                 }   # END of While Loop
46.                         }
47. #return @array;             # Return the collected results in an array.
48. close HANDLE1;              # Close the file handle.
49.  }      # END of the Program.




#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#

The error message is :

Modification of a read-only value attempted at stats_parser.pl line 23 (#1)
(F) You tried, directly or indirectly, to change the value of a
constant.  You didn't, of course, try "2 = 1", because the compiler
catches that.  But an easy way to do the same thing is:

    sub mod { $_[0] = 1 }
    mod(2);

Another way is to assign to a substr() that's off the end of the string.

Yet another way is to assign to a foreach loop VAR when VAR
is aliased to a constant in the look LIST:

        $x = 1;
        foreach my $n ($x, 2) {
            $n *= 2; # modifies the $x, but fails on attempt to modify the 2
        }

Uncaught exception from user code:
Modification of a read-only value attempted at stats_parser.pl line 23.
at stats_parser.pl line 23
main::config_parser('O3CPU.py', 'config.ini') called at stats_parser.pl line                    13
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is perl doesn't like your nested uses of the anonymous `$_` variable:

```
sub config_parser {
    foreach (@_) {
        # $_ is in scope here
        if ( !open HANDLE1, "<", "$_" ) { 
            die "Cannot open $_: $!";
        }   
        while (<HANDLE1>) {
            # This is a different $_
            chomp $_;
        }
    }   
}
```

Give your loop variables names... It will also make your code more readable. I would also recommend using lexical filehandles instead of the old-stlye GLOBAL ones.

```
sub config_parser {
    for my $filename (@_) {
        open my $fh, '<', $filename
          or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";
        while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
            chomp $line;
            if ( $line =~ (...) ) { 
                ...;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua. I have refactored my code as described. This works fine except that I get "Uninitialized $_ error in substitution s///" with $line in accessing the file. Hence I used $_ instead of $line to fix this issue and rest everything works fine now.

Comment: Your comment that "This is a different $_" is incorrect. The problem is that inside the `for` loop, `$_` is aliased to a constant (the string "O3CPU.py"), but `while <$fh>` does an automatic assignment to `$_`. You can get the same behavior by doing `$_ = "foo" for qw(bar baz)`.

Comment: Divya: The quick fix is to just use `$_` on your inner loop. Alternatively, each call to `s//` will need to refer to the var name explicitly, ie `if ( $line =~ s/foo\s+/foo / || $line =~ s/bar\s+/bar/ )`,etc.

Comment: @DivyaKiranKadiyala  It may be the following. The `$v =~ /.../  || /.../` is really `($v =~ /.../) || (/.../)`, because of precedence. But that is `($v =~ /.../) || ($_ =~ /.../)` because of regex match operator's default.  When you assign `$line = <$fh>` there is no `$_` any more (it's undef), thus the error. So either use `$_` (and no `$line`) for `if (/.../ || /.../)` or use `$line` in every match, `($line =~ /.../ || $line =~ /.../)`.

Comment: Thanks Joshua and zdim. I changed my substitution regex as ($line =~ /.../ || $line =~ /.../) and it worked fine, Thanks for the quick reply